# Are the quality of the Loot Boxes received based on RNG?

Tags: overwatch

For my first 9 level ups I did not get any Loot Box quality higher than the common grade, the boxes with a white glow.

[image]

At level 10, I got my first "better than common" grade Loot Box, this time with a blue glow.

Some I have seen from others are boxes that come with purple and orange glows.

[image]

https://media.giphy.com/media/3o6gb7X6NwaUBI8EXS/giphy.gif

I am wondering, are the quality of Loot Boxes predetermined? Am I only set to get the rarer loot boxes when I hit bigger level milestones, such as every 10 or every 20 levels, etc.? Or is the type of Loot Box received completely random and am I just unlucky I guess?  In the common box, I actually unboxed a legendary skin, seen below, so glows only guarantee you'll get at least a rarity of whatever the glow is. Contents below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Loot_Box),

> Each Loot Box contains four random items that can be used to customize the appearance of heroes. Items come in common, rare, epic, and legendary quality levels, and every Loot Box includes at least one rare quality or better item.

and,

> even unopened Loot Boxes will glow in a color corresponding to what items are inside.

so if you haven't gotten a box before with a different glow, you just were unlucky that you hadn't gotten as rare of items in your previous loot boxes.

Comment: I'm not talking about the contents of the loot box, I'm talking about the rarity of the loot box itself. Loot boxes come in 4 rarities supposedly, common which is white, uncommon which is blue, rare which is purple, and legendary which is golden

Comment: @O-O do you have any source for that? the wiki states that the color of the glow just reflects the items inside of it, nothing about there being different tiers of loot boxes

Comment: If you look up images on google images for loot boxes, you will see some boxes have blue glows, some have purple glows and some have golden glows. I have received purple items from common boxes as well

Comment: I re-edited the question to better reflect it. As far as I know, glows on boxes, as you said, guarantee an item of said quality, but sometimes boxes can come in a legendary glow, before you open it, or a purple glow

Comment: @O-O i'll do some more research on it, but I have yet to hear anywhere anything about loot box tiers

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear.  What I mean is, in the gif I linked above, you'll notice it has an orange glow. I have never received one of these, but you are guaranteed a legendary item (most likely skin), unlike lower tier glows, which can give you a legendary but are not guaranteed.

Comment: @O-O I think I'm understanding you, and I think the answer is that the color/rank of the box is random because the contents of the boxes are random. Maybe I'm not being clear either, not sure.

Comment: The lootbox colors seem to have been removed from the game entirely at some point.  Having said that, the contents of a loot box are [generated at the time you receive it](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20746654483), so don't bother storing them to try to get stuff for a hero that's going to be released soon.